# What's the difference between $|z|^2$ and $z^2$, where $z$ is a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that $|z|^2=zz^*$ but what is $z^2$? Is it simply $z^2=(a+ib)^2$?

Comment: Yes. Worth expanding out and more or less memorizing the result. It comes up again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z=a+ib$, then

\begin{align*}
z^2=&\,z\times z=(a+ib)\times(a+ib),\\
\left|z\right|^2=&\,z\times\overline z=(a+ib)\times(a-ib).
\end{align*}

Note that $\left|z\right|^2$ is always real and non-negative, whereas $z^2$ is, in general, complex.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that $|z|^2$ is always a non-negative real number, where $z^2$ is frequently a complex number.

$z^2 = a^2 +2abi - b^2$ whereas $|z|^2 = a^2 + b^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$z^2 -|z|^2 = a^2 + 2abi - b^2 - a^2 - b^2 = 2abi - 2b^2 = 2b(ai-b) = 2bzi$

Similarly, $z^2+|z|^2=a^2+2abi-b^2+a^2+b^2=2a^2+2abi=2a(a+bi) = 2az$